# Why is Jackson serializing numeric fields to Strings?

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

I have the following Jersey resource, Jersey has been configured to use Jackson for automatic JSON-POJO conversion:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {
    @POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public TestResponse testGet(final TestRequest req) {
        final TestResponse response = new TestResponse();
        response.x = req.x + 1;
        return response;
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class TestRequest {
        public int x;
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class TestResponse {
        public int x;
    }
}
```

I call this with:

```
{"x":5}
```

And get the response:

```
{"x":"6"}
```

But why is the value here a string, when the x field in TestResponse is an int?

Comment: Everything gets serialized to String by default. I'm not sure why this is an issue for the client.

Comment: Hmm, weird - how can I change this behavior?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous example, it's definitely possible to configure Jersey to provide you with the behavior you expect. However, it actually looks like Jersey is using the default MAPPING notation and not using Jackson at all. I would review how you have Jackson configured into your web application. The easiest way for me to configure Jackson was to create the following two files...

- META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader
- META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter

Both of those files contain only the following text...

```
org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
```

[Here is a link explaining the two ways to configure Jackson to work with JAX-RS annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ#JAX-RS)

Comment: How do you know it is using the default mapping notation?

Answer (score -1):

You can use nonStrings(): http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#d4e1011

Or check out natural notation: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#d4e1058